# How to fix a broken sizeHint in core controls modified by a stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

I have an application that styles `QAbstractSpinBox` using an application-wide stylesheet, that goes like this:

```css
QAbstractSpinBox {
    border: 2px inset grey;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    qproperty-buttonSymbols: PlusMinus;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::up-button
{
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
    right: 1px;
}

QAbstractSpinBox::down-button
{
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

The objective here is to obtain spinboxes with +/- buttons on the sides, like this:

[image: example of a QSpinBox with +/- buttons on the sides]

While the look is ok, the control does not behave correctly in layouts; in particular, the `sizeHint()` is wrong, as can be seen here for the `QDoubleSpinBox`:

[image: two QSpinBox and two QDoubleSpinBox, where QDoubleSpinBoxes have clearly wrong sizeHint]

Experimenting a bit, it turned out that it's not taking into account the size needed for one of the buttons; I don't want to replace each and every `QAbstractSpinBox` derived classes with my own subclassed version that fixes the `sizeHint()`, so I went at the bottom of the issue and checked how `QAbstractSpinBox` implements its `sizeHint()` so look for hints:

```
QSize QAbstractSpinBox::sizeHint() const
{
    Q_D(const QAbstractSpinBox);
    if (d->cachedSizeHint.isEmpty()) {
        ensurePolished();

        const QFontMetrics fm(fontMetrics());
        int h = d->edit->sizeHint().height();
        int w = 0;
        QString s;
        QString fixedContent =  d->prefix + d->suffix + QLatin1Char(' ');
        s = d->textFromValue(d->minimum);
        s.truncate(18);
        s += fixedContent;
        w = qMax(w, fm.horizontalAdvance(s));
        s = d->textFromValue(d->maximum);
        s.truncate(18);
        s += fixedContent;
        w = qMax(w, fm.horizontalAdvance(s));

        if (d->specialValueText.size()) {
            s = d->specialValueText;
            w = qMax(w, fm.horizontalAdvance(s));
        }
        w += 2; // cursor blinking space

        QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);
        QSize hint(w, h);
        d->cachedSizeHint = style()->sizeFromContents(QStyle::CT_SpinBox, &opt, hint, this)
                            .expandedTo(QApplication::globalStrut());
    }
    return d->cachedSizeHint;
}
```

Which essentially calculates a size for the internal textbox part considering the maximum width that the content can assume (using the max/min/special text), and then delegates calculating the full size to `QStyle::sizeFromContents` from the current style. In turn, the relevant portion in `QStyleSheetStyle::sizeFromContents` is this:

```
    case CT_SpinBox:
        if (const QStyleOptionSpinBox *spinbox = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionSpinBox *>(opt)) {
            if (spinbox->buttonSymbols != QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons) {
                // Add some space for the up/down buttons
                QRenderRule subRule = renderRule(w, opt, PseudoElement_SpinBoxUpButton);
                if (subRule.hasDrawable()) {
                    QRect r = positionRect(w, rule, subRule, PseudoElement_SpinBoxUpButton,
                                           opt->rect, opt->direction);
                    sz.rwidth() += r.width();
                } else {
                    QSize defaultUpSize = defaultSize(w, subRule.size(), spinbox->rect, PseudoElement_SpinBoxUpButton);
                    sz.rwidth() += defaultUpSize.width();
                }
            }
            if (rule.hasBox() || rule.hasBorder() || !rule.hasNativeBorder())
                sz = rule.boxSize(sz);
            return sz;
        }
        break;
```

Without going into the details, it's clear that only the Up button is considered, and only for its width, with the underlying assumption that the two buttons are stacked vertically; the down button is ignored completely.

I tried to work around the problem by means of a custom `QStyle`:

```
struct GLProxyStyle : QProxyStyle {
    virtual QSize sizeFromContents(ContentsType ct, const QStyleOption *opt, const QSize &contentsSize, const QWidget *w) const override {
        QSize ret = QProxyStyle::sizeFromContents(ct, opt, contentsSize, w);
        if (ct == CT_SpinBox) {
            if (const QStyleOptionSpinBox *spinbox = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionSpinBox *>(opt)) {
                if (spinbox->buttonSymbols != QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons) {
                    QRect downRect = subControlRect(CC_SpinBox, spinbox, SC_SpinBoxDown, w);
                    QRect upRect = subControlRect(CC_SpinBox, spinbox, SC_SpinBoxDown, w);
                    if (downRect.left() != upRect.left()) {
                        ret.rwidth() += downRect.width();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

but unfortunately setting a stylesheet makes it override `QStyle`.

For now I'm forcing a minimum size depending on an adjusted size hint after building all widgets, but that's a pain and, most importantly, it introduces a relayout, so I'd like to find a way to fix the `sizeHint()` globally.

So, coming to my question:

- is there a way to override the `QStyleSheetStyle` implementation of `sizeFromContents`?
- or, more in general: is there some other way to fix this that I missed?

Comment: Shouldn't `QRect upRect = subControlRect(CC_SpinBox, spinbox, SC_SpinBoxDown, w);` be `QRect upRect = subControlRect(CC_SpinBox, spinbox, SC_SpinBoxUp, w);`?  Otherwise, I have much the same question...

Comment: @eclarkso oh dear, maybe it was just that typo? I'll check it ASAP, thank you!

Comment: @eclarkso: retried fixing the typo, unfortunately it still doesn't work... which matches the investigation I did at the time (if you use a stylesheet, `QProxyStyle` is powerless).

Comment: Yes unfortunately I wasn't too hopeful that would actually fix anything.  But I did find your question (and code) helpful for my own workaround in the proper way to extract the button subcontrol size info, so thank you!  My own hack fix is to use `setMinimumSize` and a variation on your `ProxyStyle` so that it doesn't get too narrow...